# Change order of product info on product page

Tags: css, magento, layout, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I know this can be done with `before` and `after` on a layout file but is there anybody who can explain it to me? Let's say for example I want to put the `short description` under "price", or just switch places. Or put the `price` where `SKU` is. I would like someone to explain how this works and how I can achieve this. 
Also, is it possible to do it by category?

I would really appreciate some help. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The first phtml file to check is probably `yourtheme/template/catalog/product/view.phtml`.

If you do a Ctrl+find in that file, you'll find the position of those attributes (`short_description`,`price` etc).

For example you could cut

```
<?php if ($_product->getShortDescription()):?>
                <div class="short-description">
                    <div class="std"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()), 'short_description') ?></div>
                </div>
            <?php endif;?>
```

and paste it under the end of `<div class="price-info">...</div>`

(right click Inspect element is your friend

I suggest you also enable template path hints. Go to `admin->system`, change the current configuration scope to one of your stores (near the top left), then click developer (developer is in the bottom left). Then in the Debug menu in the center, change Template Path Hints to Yes. This allows you to see which template phtml files serve which parts of your frontend.)

Comment: Thank you very much kaska, this is what I needed. Thumbs up.